# How can I pause PotPlayer reliably using the "Space" hotkey, regardless of current window?

Tags: hotkeys, daum-pot-player

If I click on its browser window or playlist window before minimizing, the "space" hotkey does not pause it when I click on it again in the taskbar and press the "space" hotkey. It only works when I clicked on the main PotPlayer window prior to minimizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a hotkey to pause/play globally, regardless of the open window and it works everywhere. Whether that is a solution to your problem is up to you, since there is no option to assign hotkeys that work only in PotPlayer windows (either the main player or playlist window).

For a global hotkey, in preferences (`F5`), go to General > Keyboard.
Add a hotkey (for example, `Ctrl + space`), assigning it to playback: play/pause. Make sure that you check global (as in the picture below).

[image: Global hotkey for playback in PotPlayer]

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I didn't check global hotkey because I thought it was a button to simply select it, rather than a config option.